# Selecting a Cell by it's position (Left,Top)

Tags: vba, excel, coordinates

I'm creating a sales channel map and use the .Left/.Top w/  + (.5*.width/.Height) to get the center of the images I'm connecting. I'd like to also use this method to select the cell that corresponds to this coordinate.

The only solution I can think of (and could implement, but I'd rather avoid an iterative approach) would be something like:

```
Sub FindCellLoc(DesiredYLocation,DesiredXLocation)
'Finds the Column Number of the X coordinate
RunningTotalX = 0
For X = 1 to 100000000
    RunningTotalX = RunningTotalX + Cells(1,X).width
    if RunningTotalX >= DesiredXLocation then
        TargetCol = Cells(1,X).Column
        Goto FoundCol
    End if
Next X
FoundCol:
'Finds the Column Number of the X coordinate
RunningTotalY = 0
For Y = 1 to 100000000
    RunningTotalY = RunningTotalY + Cells(Y,1).width
    if RunningTotalY >= DesiredYLocation then
        TargetRow = Cells(Y,0).Column
        Goto FoundRow
    End if
Next Y
FoundRow
Cells(TargetRow,TargetCol).Select
End Sub
```

I'd really appreciate any input about a non-iterative approach.

Thanks,
-E

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a routine to select a cell based on the x and y position:

```
Public Sub SelectCellByPos(x, y)
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLine(x, y, x, y)
        .TopLeftCell.Select
        .Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't seem to pass variables to this code, I'm not familiar with your use of "!" here, can you explain please?

The premise is to draw a dot (line) then locate the cell reference from that point (Same idea as Mr. Kusleika's -- and a good one at that), then delete the point with the center cell selected.

To test it I wrote the following:
    Sub Test()
    lRow = shp.Top + shp.Height \ 2
    lCol = shp.Left + shp.Width \ 2
    Call SelectCellByPos(lCol,lRow)
    end sub

Returning the "ByRef argument type mismatch"

Comment: The "!" is the Single Type Declaration Character. It is exactly the same as this: x As Single. To call the procedure, you just do this: SelectCellByPos 300, 400.

Comment: The reason you are getting the error is because you are attempting to pass variables that have not been typed as Single. Make your Col and Row variables typed as Single. Then it will work. I typed the input variables as Single because the 'x' and 'y' properties of Shapes are typed as Single, which means they accept decimal values like 400.75

Comment: @user3425324  
I have given you the most concise way possible to achieve your goal.

Comment: If you don't like the variables as Single, you can just remove the '!' character from each variable in the procedure definition. Either way works.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I've been programing in R and was confusing my languages and the bang(!). Your solution is great, and is the answer to my original question, but Kusleika's was worked better for this application. Thanks for the code and quick response!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have access to the shape object from which you got the desired locations. If so, you could do something like

```
Function GetCenterCell(shp As Shape) As Range

    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

    lRow = (shp.TopLeftCell.Row + shp.BottomRightCell.Row) \ 2
    lCol = (shp.TopLeftCell.Column + shp.BottomRightCell.Column) \ 2

    Set GetCenterCell = shp.Parent.Cells(lRow, lCol)

End Function

Sub test()

    Dim shp As Shape

    Set shp = Sheet1.Shapes(1)

    Debug.Print GetCenterCell(shp).Address

End Sub
```

That won't give you the exact middle if there isn't an exact middle. It will skew top and left as the integer division truncates (I think). But using the TopLeftCell and BottomLeftCell properties will be far superior to iterating, even if it means you're iterating through the cells in that range or some other implementation.

Comment: Thank you sir! I wasn't familiar with cell references -- that makes it much easier!

I'm using this code to set print areas around dynamically generated images -- this will help tremendously

-E

Comment: Your answer is what I was looking for, but Excel Hero's better answers my exact question -- thank you for the contribution!

Comment: Anybody can answer questions that are asked. It's answering the ones that aren't asked that's the hard part. :)